# como ver si existe en mi base de datos en un POST de api

Tags: php, sql, api, mvc

Estoy trabajando con mi API en postman... Mi duda es que estoy haciendo un POST para insertar en la BD y tengo un campo en mi tabla que es Genero_ID que es la clave foranea y que esta asociada a la tabla Generos en Genero_ID tambien. Lo que yo quiero es que para poder hacer un POST si yo no ingreso el Genero_ID que exista en mi base de datos poder mandar un mensaje que no existe con su codigo de error... No se me ocurre como lograrlo alguien me podría ayudar? Espero haber sido claro.

Hago MVC: Este seria mi controlador de api

```
    $game = $this->getData();

    if (empty($game->Nombre) || empty($game->Fecha) || empty($game->Precio) || empty($game->Descripcion)|| empty($game->Genero_ID)) {
        $this->view->response("Complete los datos", 400);
    } 
    
    else {

        $id = $this->model->InsertGame($game->Nombre, $game->Fecha, $game->Precio, $game->Descripcion,$game->Genero_ID);
        $game = $this->model->getGame($id);
        $this->view->response($game, 201);
        
    
}


}


Este seria mi Model de consulta:


function InsertGame ($nombre,$fecha,$precio,$Descripcion,$genero) {
$query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO juegos (Nombre,Fecha,Precio,Descripcion,Genero_ID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)');
$query->execute([$nombre,$fecha,$precio,$Descripcion,$genero]);
return $this->db->lastInsertId();}



Espero haber sido claro, muchas gracias!!
```

Comment: El código que publicaste no funciona? o es lo que tienes hecho que si funciona?

Comment: Sisi funciona, pero cuando pongo un Genero_ID que no existe me tira erro de SQL.